# Configuring build.lua to install images

Tags: external-files, l3build

I have a bunch of logos I want to package up into a module within a LaTeX bundle.  But my `build.lua` file won't install them.

I have a subdirectory `logos` a the top level of my bundle.  In that directory, I have many images in EPS, PDF, SVG, PNG, and JPG format.  I have one documentation file `logos.tex` which is supposed to include them all.  My `build.lua` has these variables set:

```
bundle = "mybundle"
module = "logos"    
maindir = ".."

installfiles = {"*.eps", "*.svg", "*.pdf", "*.png", "*.jpg"}
tdsroot = "generic"
typesetfiles = {"logos.tex"}
typesetexe = "xelatex"
cleanfiles = {"*.log", "logos.pdf", "*.zip"}
```

I can compile `logos.tex` manually within the `logos` directory.  But if I run `l3build install`, nothing happens.  And if I run `l3build doc`, the compilation fails, because the images aren't being copied over to the build directory.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`installfiles` is about what gets copied *once things are extracted* from sources. So you need to make sure `l3build` also knows they are source files. I'm not clear whether the files are documentation sources or should go in the live tree, but for the moment try adding a `sourcefiles` line and listing these images plus your 'real' sources.

Comment: That seems to have done it.  I added a variable `imagefiles` and made sure `sourcefiles` and `installfiles` included it.